# Arraylist java remove next element

Tags: java, arraylist

In my problem I have a case where I want to remove the element after the word I specify. Here is my code where I remove the element itself but how would I remove the element afterwards. Its bit tricky because I have a while loop inside which reads from file all the input. Then it stores that in an array list named words.

```
 File file1 = new File(args[0]);
        File file2 = new File(args[1]);
        Scanner input = new Scanner (file1);
        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            String word = input.next();
            words.add(word);
            if(word.contains("e")){
                words.remove(word);
            }
        }
```

Output:
[Test, 1, 3, 3, -1, -2, 3, Test, 2, 1, 2, 1, -1, Test, 3, 5, 8, 5, -4, -2, 1, 3, -2, -5, 1, 4, -4, -2, -3, -3, 4, 5, 1, -2, 5, 3, -2, 5, 2, 3, -4, Test, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, -3, 1, -2, -1, -3, -2, 3, -1]
I want to remove the next element after test in every place and test itself too.

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to add the element to the list only after you've checked if it should be added in the first place.

Comment: So see if the word is "Test" and then if it is don't add it and also read the nextLine and do nothing with it.

Comment: Yup that is where I went wrong. Understand it now thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
 File file1 = new File(args[0]);
    File file2 = new File(args[1]);
    Scanner input = new Scanner (file1);
    while (input.hasNext())
    {
        String word = input.next();
        if(!word.contains("e"))
             words.add(word);
        else
             input.next();
    }
```

So something like this? It will check if the word contains an `e` fist and if it doesn't it will add it to the list. But if it does it won't add it and it will also just read the next input and do nothing with it.

Comment: Yes thats what i"m looking for. That makes alot of sense

Answer (score 0):

Probably syntax issues but here is what I'd do, warning: psudocode

```
var inputArray = input.split(',');
var removeValue = 0;

//itterate through array delimited by commas
for (i = 0; i < inputArray.count(); i++)
{
     //if flagged for removal, remove
     if (removeValue = 1)
        inputArray.removeAt(i);

     //flag next value for removal or not
     if (inputArray[i] == 'test')
       removeValue = 1;
     else
       removeValue = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I see where your getting at in this case but I have to get input from file first so it wouldn't work. The case above works if I have all my elements

Comment: make the above a function that returns a string and call it when reading the file.

Comment: Yup I understand what your saying. That would work too. I used the method above but thanks for the help